# I'm trying to send an email using the following code and I'm getting Internal Server Error

Tags: server, smtp, intervals

I'm trying to send an email using the following code and I'm getting Internal Server Error.
[image]

Comment: check if `sendmail` installed ?

Comment: yepp, it's installed.I could not see the error in the code

Comment: include output of server log if it is running in apache, ( error.log or access.log )